# Redirect with HTACCESS without any index files

Tags: .htaccess

I have a domain, but it has no files on the webhost. I want to know if it's possible to do the following with only a .htaccess on my webhost.

But what I want to use this basically for is that I want to redirect my web root `http://(www.)mydomain.net` to `http://domain2.net`. And I want `http://(www.)mydomain.com/1/` redirect to `domain3.net`.

Can anybody help me out?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the htaccess `Redirect` line..

i think it would be this (i didn't check to verify it works... but fiddle with it):

```
Redirect http://mydomain.net http://domain2.net
Redirect http://mydomain.net/1 http://domain3.net
```

http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/242/How+do+I+redirect+my+site+using+a+.htaccess+file%3F

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with s simple 301 directive mixed with directories:

I would point mydomain1.com to ip xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/mydomain1 and then in the htaccess in that directory:

```
Redirect 301 / http://domain1.net/
```

Then you can repeat the same for site 2:  point site to to ip xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/mydomain2 and in the htaccess for that directory

```
Redirect 301 / http://domain2.net/
```